# How to configure Apache and Tomcat with vhosts?

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain, virtualhost, tomcat

I have a server with a static, public IP address. I also have a registered domain name.

For the sake of illustration, let's suppose they are

- IP Address: `12.34.56.78`
- Domain Name: `example.com`

I have a single machine on which I am running the following:

1. A website (over IIS7) available locally at `localhost:80`
2. A JetBrains TeamCity instance (over Tomcat) available locally at `localhost:1234`
3. A VisualSVN Server instance (over Apache) available locally at `localhost:5678/svn`

I have set up an A record for example.com and the following CNAME records:

- `www.example.com`
- `builds.example.com`
- `sources.example.com`

I would like to configure Tomcat and Apache such that:

- if I point my browser at `builds.example.com`, I end up at the JetBrains TeamCity instance and,
- if I point my browser at `sources.example.com`, I end up at the VisualSVN Server instance.

I thought I could configure the Apache to vhost `example.com:5678/svn` to point to `sources.example.com` and added the following lines to the Apache httpd.conf file

```
Listen 5678

NameVirtualHost *:5678

<VistualHost *:5678>
  ServerName sources.example.com
  DocumentRoot /svn
</virtualHost>
```

That broke the VisualSVN instance, so I had to revert that to

```
Listen 5678
```

Help!

Comment: typo alert: you have <VistualHost *:5678> with an s instead of an r.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the apache server as a proxy, blindly forwarding the requests to the sites. To configure the apache server to act as a proxy, you need something like this in the config file:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Proxy>

NameVirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
    ServerName sources.example.com

    ProxyPass        / http://localhost:5678/svn/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5678/svn/
</VirtualHost>
```